# how to store big size file in local android device with encrypted format

Tags: java, android, encryption, local-storage, file-handling

I am working on a video base android app which work in offline mode. For this we store video in the android device,
  what is the best way to store data (video file )in device and it will open and run in my App only.

i tried to encryt the video file and store in device but facing Following  issue :-

video size is more then 300 Mb and it takes too much time for encrytion and decryption ( approximately time is  more then 1 - 2 minutes )
    but i need to minimise this time to 2-3 second. 
what is the best way to do this

I am using following two ways for encrytion and decryption

```
1. whole file at one time  

 public static byte[] encode(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length, EncoDecode.KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(EncoDecode.CIPHER_ALGORITHM);//, EncoDecode.PROVIDER
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    return cipher.doFinal(fileData);


}

public static byte[] decode(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] decrypted;
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(EncoDecode.CIPHER_ALGORITHM);//, EncoDecode.PROVIDER
    Log.d("", "decode() returned: " + cipher.getBlockSize());
    Utility.checkmemory(mContext);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, yourKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    Utility.checkmemory(mContext);
    decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
    return decrypted;
}
```

#

```
 2. byte -to byto encrytion or decrytion
  /**
 * Encrypt and save to disk
 *
 * @return
 */
private boolean encrypt() {
    updateUI("Encrypting file...");
    pDialog.setMessage("Encrypt start..");
    pDialog.show();
    try {

        Log.e(TAG, "encrypt: starting.... " );
        Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor(EncryptDecryptUtils.getInstance(this).getSecretKey(), CIPHER_ALGORITHM, 16);

        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(path);
            os = encryptor.wrapOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathEnc));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];// change in low memory device 4096
            int nRead;
            while((nRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
                Log.e(TAG, "encrypt in process.... " );
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pDialog.setMessage("Encrypt in process...");
                    }
                });
            }
            os.flush();
        } finally {
            pDialog.setMessage("Encrypt complete...");
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(TAG, "encrypt complete.... " );
            if(is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
            if(os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        updateUI("File Encryption failed.\nException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Decrypt and return the decoded bytes
 *
 * @return
 */
private byte[] decrypt() {
    updateUI("Decrypting file...");
    pDialog.setMessage("Decrypt start..");
    pDialog.show();
    try {
  Log.e(TAG, "decrypt start !!! " );
        Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor(EncryptDecryptUtils.getInstance(this).getSecretKey(), CIPHER_ALGORITHM, 16);
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;

        try {
            is = encryptor.wrapInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathEnc));
            os = new FileOutputStream(pathDec);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int nRead;
            while((nRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "decrypt in porocess.... " );
                os.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pDialog.setMessage("Decrypt in process...");
                    }
                });
            }
            os.flush();
        } finally {
            pDialog.setMessage("Decrypt complete...");
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(TAG, "decrypt complete !!! " );
            if(is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
            if(os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        updateUI("File Decryption failed.\nException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: did you check the copy time? With this one can discuss the overload of encryption.

Comment: You could decrypt the data as a stream (or in chunks) - decrypting wile playing. Indeed reading out 300M at once takes some time..

Comment: Exo player don't support  decryption between stream . that's way we have to decrypt the video before playing. The video is store local device